# VBA Macro is ignoring nextBlankRow and duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

**What I want the Macro to accomplish:**

*I want the user to be able to fill in data from E2 to E9 on the spreadsheet. When the user presses the "Add Car" button the macro is supposed to be executed. The makro then should take the handwritten data, copy everything from E2:E9 and put it into a table that starts at with C13 and spans over 7 columns, always putting the new set of data in the next free row. It is also supposed to check for duplicates and give an alert while not overwriting the original set of data*

So my problem is, that I want the Macro I'm writing to take the information put into certain cells and then copy them into a table underneath.

I'm starting the Macro like this

```vb
Sub addData()

Dim lastrow As Long, nextBlankRow As Long
lastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

nextBlankRow = lastrow + 1
```

Here I try to define how the Macro is supposed to find the last empty cell and also define lastrow and nextBlankRow.

After that I'm starting with a simple `If` statement to see if the person has at least something in `E2` on the same sheet.

```vb
If Range("E2") = "" Then
     MsgBox "Wählen Sie ein KFZ aus!"
     Range("E2").Select
  Exit Sub
End If
```

This works. When I'm not putting something into `E2` I get the textbox with the alert.

Anyway if the IF-Statement is not triggered to exit the sub the Macro is given the instructions to get the information and put it in the table below

```vb
Cells(nextBlankRow, 3) = Range("E2")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 4) = Range("E3")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 5) = Range("E4")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 6) = Range("E5")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 7) = Range("E6")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 8) = Range("E7")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 9) = Range("E8")
```

Here seems to be a problem that probably relates to me failing to define variables correctly?

Because the Macro finds the right row but only overwrites into that row. So it ignores the fact that it "should" skip to the nextBlankrow which I defined earlier as

```vb
nextBlankRow = lastrow + 1
```

In addition to that I also have a line of code inplace which is supposed to check for duplicates

```vb
Dim p As Long, q As Long
p = 13
q = p + 1
Do While Cells(p, 3) <> ""
    Do While Cells(q, 3) <> ""
        If Cells(p, 3) = Cells(q, 3) And Cells(p, 4) = Cells(q, 4) Then
            MsgBox "Datensatz schon vorhanden!"
            Range(Cells(q, 3), Cells(q, 9)).ClearContents
        Else
        q = q + 1
        End If
    Loop
p = p + 1
q = p + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Which always gives a false return. So even if the same set of Data is copied twice into the same row (as it does) it only "refreshes" the data and doesn't say "you're not allowed to do that".

I'm at a loss here.

Here's the full code for ease of use

````vb
Sub addData()

Dim lastrow As Long, nextBlankRow As Long
lastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

nextBlankRow = lastrow + 1


If Range("E2") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Wählen Sie ein KFZ aus!"
        Range("E2").Select
    Exit Sub
End If

  Cells(nextBlankRow, 3) = Range("E2")
  Cells(nextBlankRow, 4) = Range("E3")
  Cells(nextBlankRow, 5) = Range("E4")
  Cells(nextBlankRow, 6) = Range("E5")
  Cells(nextBlankRow, 7) = Range("E6")
  Cells(nextBlankRow, 8) = Range("E7")
  Cells(nextBlankRow, 9) = Range("E8")


Dim p As Long, q As Long
p = 13
q = p + 1
Do While Cells(p, 3) <> ""
    Do While Cells(q, 3) <> ""
        If Cells(p, 3) = Cells(q, 3) And Cells(p, 4) = Cells(q, 4) Then
            MsgBox "Datensatz schon vorhanden!"
            Range(Cells(q, 3), Cells(q, 9)).ClearContents
        Else
        q = q + 1
        End If
    Loop
p = p + 1
q = p + 1
Loop


End Sub
```![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJozM.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q90Ah.jpg)
````

Comment: Can you edit the question and better explain **only in words** what you try accomplishing, please? A pictures with what you have and another one with what you need will also help, I think... The code looks complicated for something I think can be done in a mure compact way.

Comment: I have edited the original Post. I'm unfortunately not able to provide screenshots as I'm working in an secure enviroment and can't get files outside of our intranet. Also signed a policy to not take a photo of the screens. I'm sorry.

Comment: When you talk about "put it into **a table** that starts at with C13", do you try speaking about a real table (a `ListObject`), or do you speak about a simple `Range`? Then, all the rows, starting from 13 to 21, have the same number of records/values? I mean, if the code will determine the next empty row of the 13th row, will it be OK? And, finally, when speak about "check for duplicates and give an alert while not overwriting the original set of data", what do you mean by that? Theoretically, if the next empty row is well determined, no overwriting should occur,

Comment: Should the code check if you press the button by mistake, before any value has been modified in the range "E2:E9"?

Comment: Yes the table I'm talking about is a simple `range` .
Yes when the code will determine the next empty row of the 13th, so practically speaking the 14th row, it will be ok. Thats even what its supposed to do.

And yes it should check if it was pressed by mistake. That works though. The simple `if` statement that checks E2 (only E2 is important for duplicates) is working correctly.

Comment: OK. I will post a piece of code. But, I think that all values should be checked. The user inputting the data may use the same value for the first cell, I think...

Comment: Mhm okay. Is there a way to send you a picture of the sheet directly? Because I am new and don't have 10 rep so I basically can't post pictures

Comment: I think it is not necessary now. Please, test the code I posted and we'll see if I correctly understood your need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub copyRangeOnLastEmptyRow()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, lastERow As Long, matchCel As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range("E2:E9").value
 lastERow = sh.Range("C" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
 If lastERow < 13 Then lastERow = 13
 'check if the range has not been alredy copied:
 Set matchCel = sh.Range("C13:C" & lastERow - 1).Find(WHAT:=sh.Range("E2").value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
 If Not matchCel Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox sh.Range("E2").value & " has been found in cell " & matchCel.Address & "."
    'bring up the data of the existing row:
    sh.Range("E3:E9").value = Application.Transpose(sh.Range(matchCel.Offset(0, 1), matchCel.Offset(0, 7)).value)
    Exit Sub
End If
 sh.Range("C" & lastERow).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).value = Application.Transpose(arr)
 sh.Range("E2:E9").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233819/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-macro-is-ignoring-nextblankrow-and-duplicat).